Vim to drag current selected multi lines up
How do we have neovim to drag up current selected multi lines as
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('x', 'I', ":m '<-2<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })

or:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('x', 'I', ":move '<-2<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })

failed?

I can't reproduce your problem your problem. How do you select the line (using the keyboard or the mouse)? Could you share more information about the version of Neovim you are using and the Operating System you are running (Windows, Linux, macOS)?

I would do:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', 'I', ":move '<-2<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })

The x flag make the mapping only working in Visual mode.
If you select the text using the mouse you switch Neovim to Select mode in such case it is better to use the v flag that make the mapping active on both the Visual mode the Select mode.

I wonder if this is something Neovim did differently; the mouse in Vim uses Visual mode.
